# ERROR: SList.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `SLNode::SLNode()' while trying to INSERT node to linked list head C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to insert a node to the head of a linked list I have created but keep getting an error while trying to compile. The error says that I have an undefined reference to the function I am trying to call inside my insertHead function in the SList class.

**SList.cpp**:

```
/*
 * SList.cpp
 *
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 26 Oct
 *
 * References:
 */

#include "SList.h"

SList::SList() {
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

SList::~SList() {
    SList::clear();
}

void SList::insertHead(int value) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new SLNode();
    } else {

    }
}

void SList::removeHead() {
    if (head != NULL)
        head = NULL;            
}

void SList::clear() {
    head = NULL;
}

unsigned int SList::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

string SList::toString() const {
    stringstream ss;
    /*
    if (head == NULL) {
        return "";    
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < (size-1); i++) {
           ss << head[i] << ", "; 
        }
        ss << head[size-1];
    }
    */
    return "hello";
}
```

**SList.h**:

```
/*
 * SList.cpp
 *
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 26 Oct
 *
 * References:
 */

#ifndef SLIST_H
#define SLIST_H

#include "SLNode.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class SLNode;
class SList {
public:
    SList();

    ~SList();

    void insertHead(int value);

    void removeHead();

    void clear();

    unsigned int getSize() const;

    string toString() const;

private:
    SLNode* head;
    unsigned int size;
};

#endif
```

SLNode.cpp:

```
/*
 * SLNode.cpp
 * 
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 20 oct
 * 
 * References: 
 */
#include "SLNode.h"


SLNode::SLNode() {
    nextNode = NULL;
    contents = 0;
}

SLNode::SLNode(int value) {
    nextNode = NULL;
    contents = value;
}

SLNode::~SLNode() {
    nextNode = NULL;
}

void SLNode::setContents(int newContent) {
    contents = newContent;
}

int SLNode::getContents() const {
    return contents;
}

void SLNode::setNextNode(SLNode* newNode) {
    nextNode = newNode;
}

SLNode* SLNode::getNextNode() const {
    return nextNode;
}
```

**SLNode.h**:

```
/*
 * SLNode.cpp
 * 
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 20 oct
 * 
 * References: 
 */

#ifndef SLNODE_H
#define SLNODE_H

class SList;
class SLNode {

public:
    SLNode();

    SLNode(int contents);

    ~SLNode();

    void setContents(int newContent);

    int getContents() const;

    void setNextNode(SLNode* newNode);

    SLNode* getNextNode() const;

private:
    SLNode* nextNode;
    int contents;
};
#endif
```

Makefile:

```
# Target for programming challenge-18
# Date completed: 10-26-2015
pc18: pc18.cpp SList.cpp SList.h SLNode.cpp SLNode.h
    g++ -o challenge-18 pc18.cpp SList.cpp SLNode.h
```

Comment: How do you build your application? You *do* build with the `SLNode.cpp` file, or the object file generated by it?

Comment: Sorry if my response is a bit ignorant, I am still learning and I might not exactly get what you are asking. If by build you mean what actually uses my classes, then the main file is the one that builds my application by using the files I provided. Main links to SList.h which links to SLNode.h. I didn't include my main.cpp but I can if it helps?

Comment: No I really mean how do you *build* you application, how to do you compile the source files? How do you link the object files? Do you use an IDE or the command line?

Comment: @CarlosEscobedo How do you convert the source files into a program?

Comment: I use a browser based IDE called cloud9 www.c9.io and it has a terminal that I use along with a makefile I wrote.

Comment: Then please edit your question to include the makefile too.

Comment: I think I found the error. On the last line of my make file I wrote SLNode.h instead of SLNode.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Since `SLNode` is only used in `SList.cpp` at that one point, I'm guessing that your compile command doesn't compile `SLNode.cpp`

Comment: I also noticed that I wrote: g++ -o challenge-18 pc18.cpp SList.cpp SLNode.h, instead of writing SLNode.cpp on my makefile? once I fixed that the error went away.

Comment: Ah, yes. Think I posted before seeing your edit showing the Makefile.